# Sorting array of objects by property in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, object

I have an array of objects, each with various properties, and I would like to figure out how to run "sort" on the array, specifying a specific property of each object to sort by.

For example, say my objects are "chairs" and I want to sort by the property of numlegs (number of legs), then I would be able to run a sort function on an array of chairs, and it would sort them by the number of legs they have like "sort(chairs,numlegs)". Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Sorting object array

- define a class

_

```
classdef SimpleClass
    properties
        id
        numlegs
    end
    methods
        function obj = SimpleClass(id,numlegs)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.id = id;
                obj.numlegs = numlegs;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

- sort

_

```
chairs = SimpleClass.empty(20,0);
for ii = 1:20
    chairs(ii) = SimpleClass(ii, randi(4,1));
end
[~, ind] = sort([chairs.numlegs]);
chairs_sorted = chairs(ind);
```

Output

_

```
>> [chairs_sorted.numlegs]

ans =

  Columns 1 through 10

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     3

  Columns 11 through 20

     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4

>> [chairs_sorted.id]

ans =

  Columns 1 through 10

     3     5     8     9    10    11    17    19    12     1

  Columns 11 through 20

     2     4     6     7    14    15    20    13    16    18
```

### Sorting structure array

```
chairs = struct('id',num2cell(1:20), 'numlegs',num2cell(randi(4, 1, 20)));
[~, ind] = sort([chairs.numlegs]);
chairs_sorted = chairs(ind);
```